# How to access a variable from another dart file . Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter and I need to access a variable from another dart file.I am using showDatePicker to select a date.I need to get that date in another file in which where dob.dart is calling to insert in database.

**dob.dart**

```
class _DateOfBirthState extends State<DateOfBirth> {
  DateTime? dateTime;
  String _text = '';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
      ),
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            const Text('Date Of Birth'),
            Text(_text),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                dateTime = await showDatePicker(
                  context: context,
                  initialDate: dateTime ?? DateTime.now(),
                  firstDate: DateTime(1900),
                  lastDate: DateTime.now(),
                );
                setState(() {
                  _text =
                      '${dateTime?.day}/${dateTime?.month}/${dateTime?.year}';
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Date Of Birth'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I need to use value of dateTime in another file addStudents.dart

**addstudents.dart**

```
class _AddStudentsState extends State<AddStudents> {
  final _nameController = TextEditingController();
  final _addressController = TextEditingController();
  final _mobileController = TextEditingController();
  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>(); @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Form(
          key: _formkey,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Enter your name';
                    }
                  },
                  controller: _nameController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Name',
                      hintText: 'Alex',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                ),                
                DateOfBirth(),               
                TextFormField(
                  maxLines: 5,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  controller: _addressController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Address',
                      hintText:
                          'House 21\nKolachery mukk\nP.O.Kolachery\nKannur\n670601',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                ),               
                TextFormField(
                  maxLength: 10,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  controller: _mobileController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Mobile Number',
                    prefixText: '+91',
                    hintText: '0000000000',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  ),
                ),                
                TextFormField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  controller: _emailController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Email',
                      hintText: 'name@example.com',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                ),         
                SizedBox(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    child: const Text('Submit'),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      if (!_formkey.currentState!.validate()) {
                        return;
                      }

                      await DataBaseHelper.instance.addStudent(
                        StudentDetails(
                          name: _nameController.text,
                          dob:
                              // '${dateTime!.day}/${dateTime!.month}/${dateTime!.year}',
                          address: _addressController.text,
                          phone: _mobileController.text,
                          email: _emailController.text,
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a constructor **onDateSelected** so you can get a datetime when you select a date from date-picker.

```
class DateOfBirth extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function onDateSelected;

  DateOfBirth({this.onDateSelected});

  @override
  _DateOfBirthState createState() => _DateOfBirthState();
}

class _DateOfBirthState extends State<DateOfBirth> {
  DateTime? dateTime;
  String _text = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            const Text('Date Of Birth'),
            Text(_text),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                dateTime = await showDatePicker(
                  context: context,
                  initialDate: dateTime ?? DateTime.now(),
                  firstDate: DateTime(1900),
                  lastDate: DateTime.now(),
                );
                widget.onDateSelected(dateTime);
                setState(() {
                  _text =
                      '${dateTime?.day}/${dateTime?.month}/${dateTime?.year}';
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Date Of Birth'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

// You can get date like this.

```
DateOfBirth(
      onDateSelected: (date) {
        //
      },
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are navigating from **dob.dart** to **addstudents.dart** then you can pass the value of DateTime though the constructor.

or

you can store it inside local database like **sharedpreferences**, and access it in any file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the file with the variable dateTime.

Then you have 2 ways:

1. make the variable static: `static var dateTime`
2. for this way you don't need todo know anything

so if you have make the variable static you can use it also in a other file if you import the file with the static varible and you use it like this: `ClassWithTheStaticVarible.dateTime`.

and if you do way number 2 than you need to import the file with the variable and you can use it like this: `ClassWithTheDateTimeVarible().dateTime`

so what it does if you use way 1: it pick the varible out of the class without build the class again.

and if you use way 2 it does: build the class again and pick after this the variable